# Expected value, function of two random variables

Tags: integration, measure-theory, probability-theory

We are given two independent random variables $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^m, \ Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and a Borel measurable function $g: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(X,Y)$ is integrable.

I'm trying to prove that $$\mathbb{E} (g(X,Y)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \mathbb{E}(g(x, Y))  \ \text{d} P_X(x) $$

I know that for $$\mathbb{E}(g(X, Y)) = \int_\mathbb{R^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} g(x,y) \ \text{d}P_Y(y) \ \text{d}P_X(x)$$

Could you help me transform this integral to get the result above?

Comment: You're trying to prove Fubini's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$E(g(X,Y))$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \bigg[ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x,y) dP_Y(y) \bigg]  dP_X(x)$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \bigg[ \int_{\Omega} g(x,Y(\omega)) dP(\omega) \bigg] dP_X(x)$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} E(g(x,Y)) dP_X(x) $

That second equality holds because $g(x,\cdot) \circ Y = g(x,Y)$, and so in other words that equality is basically saying that

$\int_{\Omega} g(x, \cdot ) \circ Y dP = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x, \cdot) dP_Y$

which we know is true, as it is one of the most fundamental properties of the measure $P_Y$.