# Average separately by independence

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, $U$ and $V$ measurable spaces, $\ X:\Omega \to U$ and $Y:\Omega \to V$ measurable mappings, $\ f:U \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ a bounded measurable function w.r.t. the product $\sigma$-algebra on $U \times V$. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Let $\mu$ be the distribution of $Y$ on the $V$-space, defined by $\mu(B)=P\{Y \in B\}$ for measurable sets $B \subseteq V$.

Now I want to show that: 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big[\ f(X,Y\ )\big] = \int_V \mathbb{E}\big[\ f(X,y\ )\big]\ \mu(dy).
\end{align}

I want to start with functions of the type $\ f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)\ $ (which other functions have to follow?) using the below theorem.

**Theorem**: let $\mathcal{R}$ be a $\pi$-system on a space $X$such that $X=\cup B_i$ for some pairwise disjoint sequence $B_i \in \mathcal{R}$. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a linear space of bounded functions on $X$. Assume that $\mathbb{1}_B \in \mathcal{H}$ for all $B \in \mathcal{R}$ and assume that $\mathcal{H}$ is closed under bounded, increasing pointwise limits. It follows from these assumptions that $\mathcal{H}$ contains all bounded $\sigma(\mathcal{R})$-measurable functions.

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, it follows that their joint law is the product of their individual laws, i.e, $P^{(X,Y)}=P^X \otimes P^Y$. The rest follows from here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196088/expected-value-function-of-two-random-variables/1196173#1196173